# Prove that every even integer n with 2 ≤ n ≤ 26 can be written as a sum of at most three perfect square

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Sorry to say. Completely I dont know about this question. I have searched in google I could not find answer . Can anyone say about this.

Comment: Doing it by hand doesn't take very long.

Comment: For such a small range, brute force is best. Simply find a representation for every number

Comment: At most?  $4=1+1+1+1\, , \;12=1+1+1+9$

Answer (score 1):

- $ 2=1+1$
- $ 4=4$
- $ 6=4+1+1$
- $ 8=4+4$
- $10=9+1$
- $12=4+4+4$
- $14=9+4+1$
- $16=16$
- $18=16+1+1$
- $20=16+4$
- $22=9+9+4$
- $24=16+4+4$
- $26=16+9+1$